# Existence of inner product over $\mathbb{Q}$ non-degenerate,without normalized orthogonal basis, anisotropic but not definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

The question came directly seeking for counterexample of the following Lemma :

$\textbf{Lemma} :$ $(V_{\mathbb{R}},\phi)$ is anisotropic $\iff \phi$ is definite.

If we restrict our view over rationals, i think although $\Leftarrow$ still holds, the other implication does not.

So the question, a little generalized would be

Exists a non-degenerate inner product of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ such that doesn't admit normalized orthogonal basis, anisotropic but not definite?

I think the answer is affirmative,but it was quite difficult to me. 
I tried a matrix of the following form : $$\begin{pmatrix}a & 1 \\ 1 & b\end{pmatrix}$$ With the condition that $\begin{cases} \phi(a,a) > 0 \\ \phi(b,b) < 0 \\ ab \ne 1 \end{cases}$

But i ended up with nothing, especially because of anisotropic condition :

$$\begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a & 1 \\ 1 & b\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = 0$$

Which gives the following conic $ax^{2}+2xy+by^{2} = 0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Any solution, help or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the "doesn't asmit orthogonal basis.." part - every symmetric bilinear form admits an orthogonal basis.

Comment: @LucaMorstabilini I think it's true just when char($\mathbb{K}$) $\ne 2$, which in this chase obviously is, you're right. When $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{F}_{2}$, take $\phi = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Note that $\phi$ is totally isotropic.If it had an orthogonal basis $B$, $M_{B}(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, which contradicts rank invariancy under congruence, since rank($\phi$) = 2.

Comment: You are right, I assumed beforehand that the characteristic was different than $2$ (as is usually assumed when studying these things). 
For your actual question, try showing that the product $\phi$ over $\mathbb{Q}^2$ represented in some basis by \begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && -2 \end{pmatrix} is non definite and anisotropic (and of course can't have an orthonormal basis, otherwise would be positive definite). This should answer your question, if I understood what you want.

Comment: @LucaMorstabilini Tried something very similar. I struggled with prooving that $\phi$ was anisotropic without success. Thank's anyway.

Comment: To prove anisotropicity, say that $v = (x, y)$ and $\phi(v, v) = 0$. This means that $x^2 = 2 y^2$. Now, $y \neq 0$ would imply $2 = \frac{x^2}{y^2}$ but $2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$. So $y = 0$, which means that $x = 0$, too.

Comment: @LucaMorstabilini Right, thanks, you solved it! I think the original question should be $\phi$ doesn't admit normalized orthogonal basis. I've edited it.